# how to concatenate environment variable with string in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project that uses html to send out an email. I pass the main domain through the environment variable EXTERNAL_URL. The button works as a clickable link when I have just the code below.

```
<a href="<%= ENV['EXTERNAL_URL'] %>" class="btn-primary" ...
```

However I am now trying to make the button point to a more specific path on the domain and I am trying to concatenate the strings like below but then the button is not clickable and is not working.

```
<a href="<%= ENV["EXTERNAL_URL"+"/#/new_match"] %>" class="btn-primary" ...
```

What is proper way to concatenate in this situation?

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket in the second example ENV["EXTERNAL_URL" <- here. And also string concatenation isn't really ruby way, you'd better interpolate them like "#{ENV......}rest of string message". And rails have nice helpers to use like link_to,that you can use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="<%= "#{ENV['EXTERNAL_URL']}/#/new_match" %>" class="btn-primary"> click here </a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the solution myself and then saw your answer. I posted my answer too above.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The way I did it was below.

```
<a href="<%= ENV['EXTERNAL_URL'] %>/#/new_match" class="btn-primary"
```